# calling a procedure throws an error ORA-30625: NULL SELF ORA-06512

Tags: loadrunner

```
lrd_ora8_handle_alloc(OraEnv1, STMT, &OraStm55, 0);
    lrd_ora8_stmt(OraStm55, "begin\n:ResultVar := PKG_LOADRST.ADDFILEDOCS( :PARAM0, :PARAM1, :PARAM2, :PARAM3);\nend;\n", 1, 0, 0);
    lrd_ora8_attr_set(OraStm55, PREFETCH_ROWS, "0", -1, 0);
    lrd_ora8_attr_set(OraStm55, PREFETCH_MEMORY, "0", -1, 0);
    lrd_assign(&PARAM0_D155, "{ID}", 0, 0, 0);
    lrd_ora8_bind_placeholder(OraStm55, &OraBnd93, "PARAM0", &PARAM0_D155, 
        0, 0, 0);
    lrd_assign(&PARAM1_D156, "RST_FILE", 0, 0, 0);
    lrd_ora8_bind_placeholder(OraStm55, &OraBnd94, "PARAM1", &PARAM1_D156, 
        0, 0, 0);
    lrd_assign(&PARAM2_D157, "0", 0, 0, 0);
    lrd_ora8_bind_placeholder(OraStm55, &OraBnd95, "PARAM2", &PARAM2_D157, 
        0, 0, 0);
    lrd_assign(&PARAM3_D158, "0", 0, 0, 0);
    lrd_ora8_bind_placeholder(OraStm55, &OraBnd96, "PARAM3", &PARAM3_D158, 
        0, 0, 0);
    lrd_assign(&RESULTVAR_D159, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    lrd_ora8_bind_placeholder(OraStm55, &OraBnd97, "RESULTVAR", &RESULTVAR_D159, 
        0, 0, 0);
    lrd_ora8_exec(OraSvc1, OraStm55, 1, 0, &uliRowsProcessed, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0);
    GRID0(118);
    lrd_handle_free(&OraStm55, 0);''

Action.c(1533): ora8_exec: ERROR, return-code=LRDE2009. 0 row(s) processed
Action.c(1533): Error: ORA-30625: їїїїїїїї їїїїї їїїїїї їїї їїїїїїїїї NULL SELF ORA-06512: її "FACT.PKG_LOADRST", line 1247 ORA-06512: її line 2
Action.c(1533): Error: lrdo_ora8_exec: "OCIStmtExecute" return-code=OCI_ERROR, error-code=30625:
```

Running the script in LoadRunner does not cause errors, and running it in the Performance Center gives errors. What is the problem?

Comment: Are the load generators the same in both cases?

Comment: load generators are different.  in the first case, the generator is my computer and the script runs on it.

Comment: Then you are looking at differences between the load generators.   Hypothesis 1, the versions of oracle client installed are different.   Hypothesis 2, the oranames file is not the same.   Hypothesis 3, the installations are different.  Install VUGEN on the remote load generator and ensure that you can run the script locally

Comment: All other scripts work fine on generators

Comment: OK.  Works on X.  Doesn't work on Y.  Make Y look and act like X.